# Около 20-ти человек или около 20 человек

Tags: числительные

Как правильно писать в новостях "около 20-ти человек или около 20 человек. И когда вообще стоит употреблять к числительным эти окончания?

Answer (score 4):

Писать надо ***около 20 человек***.

А называть ***наращения*** окончаниями не надо. 
Наращения применяются только для обозначения ***порядковых*** числительных при их написании цифрами: "21-й этаж", "На 155-м километре", "О 1054-м рейсе". При таких порядковых числительных наращения считаются обязательными - за исключением некоторых редких случаев.

Для количественных числительных наращения не применяются никогда.

Answer (score -1):

Я сам не опытен в том, что Вы прекрасно умеете делать. У Вас есть качество которым я не обладаю и поэтому хочу научиться этому. 
Перед аудиторией если зная урок полностью, я не в силах на него ответить.
Займитесь этим качеством в своей жизни и больше проявите способностей в этой сфере. 
Разница между Вашим опытом и моим не владением ситуацией перед аудиторией дает ясность ответа на Ваш вопрос. Значение людей и участие их в нашем с тобой делах могут быть одинаковы. Только взаимодействие людей вызывает сотрудничество. Примеры создающие подобие с этапами твоего характера и жизни самостоятельно выдели списком для себя. 
Почувствуем разницу, если с тобой будем продолжать это делать. В чем? По отношению к новостям или к своему опыту? В такой ситуации, числа не имеют значения. Если написать словом - "двадцати людей".
Эндрю Карнеги придавал значение к людям, а не числам. Без людей Наполеон Хилл не смог бы составить такой Курс как "Закон Успеха". Если Вам не стоит своего труда и сил поизучать этот курс, то вы сможете непредвзято относиться ко всему, что читаете.